# Google Analytics executing in a dynamically created modal window

Tags: javascript, dom, google-analytics, modal-dialog

I am using JavaScript to create a modal window when a user either clicks a link or submits a form. The modal window holds either a form if they click a link or a thank you page when a user submits a sign up form. The modal window is populated using `innerHTML`.

The issue I am having is that these modal windows have Google Analytic tags in their source code. For some odd reason the Google Analytics is not executing. I have tried to place the actual ga.js source into the pages, that didn't work. I have put the Analytics code in two separate files but that is not working either.

Any one ever ran into this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t add `script` tags using `.innerHTML`. Just fire `pageTracker._trackPageview()` directly from javascript, as it is described in the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview)